# solution of first order partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Here $k$ and $k_{1}$ are constant

$\frac{\partial }{\partial t}f\left(s ,t\right)=k{f}^{2}\left(s,t\right)-{k}_{1}f\left(s,t\right)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial t}f\left(s ,t\right)=k{f}^{2}\left(s,t\right)-{k}_{1}f\left(s,t\right)$$
Since there is no partial derivative relatively to $s$, the equation is a first order ODE :
$$\frac{df }{dt}=k{f(t)}^{2}-{k}_{1}f(t)$$
Moreover, the ODE is separable :
$$t=\int \frac{df}{k{f(t)}^{2}-{k}_{1}f(t)}=\frac{1}{k_1}\ln|\frac{kf-k_1}{f}|+c$$ 
$$f=\frac{k_1}{k-Ce^{k_1t}}$$
Then, comming back to the two variable function :
$$f(s,t)=\frac{k_1}{k-C(s)e^{k_1t}}$$
where $C(s)$ is an arbitrary function insofar no initial condition is specified.

Answer (score 0):

The differential equation is
$$\dfrac{df}{dt} = f(kf-k_1) \implies \dfrac{df}{f(f-k_1/k)}=kdt$$
Using partial fractions, we have
$$\dfrac{df}{f-\frac{k_1}k}-\dfrac{df}f = kdt$$
which on integrating gives us
$$\ln\left(f-\dfrac{k_1}k\right) - \ln(f) = kt + c \implies 1- \dfrac{k_1}{kf} = C e^{kt}$$
Now obtain $f$.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Leg!

How we (or why) write partial f as ordinary derivative?

What is the type of this PDE? First order linear PDE?